The WinRM client cannot process the request Issue
I created a GitHub Actions workflow for deploying my Laravel code from my local computer to server that which runs it via IIS.
Here is my workflow file:
name: Deploy to IIS

on:
  push:
     branches:
      - main 

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
- name: Checkout repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up PHP
  uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
  with:
    php-version: '7.1.9'

- name: Publish to IIS
  run: |
    $username = "my_username"
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "my_password" -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName my_server_name -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
        Set-Location -Path "D:\IT\APPS\example_app"
        git pull origin main
    }

With this YAML file, my purpose is pulling the main branch from the GitHub repository to related path of project folder in the server.
This server is an EC2 instance in AWS.
When I push my code to main branch, I get these error lines:
Line |
   6 |  Invoke-Command -ComputerName my_server_name -Credential $credential -Scr …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | [my_server_name] Connecting to remote server my_server_name failed with the following error message : The WinRM client
     | cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer
     | is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the
     | TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the
     | TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following
     | command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

